# Unable to install the jmeter's plugin manager

Tags: ssl, plugins, jmeter

I have apache jmeter 5.4.1, and I try to install plugin manager but not successful. After put the correct file into lib\ext, but next when I click options -> plugin manger, I will the " Javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:.........unable to find valid certification path to requested target". I am not sure what certificate I need to request target? Really appreciate any help. Thanks! [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you cannot securely connect to [JMeter Plugins repository](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/#Add-Your-Plugin-or-Repository), the default address is https://jmeter-plugins.org/repo/

Most probably your organization or ISP has a [MITM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) certificate somewhere to capture and decrypt your network traffic, you can check it using i.e. [OpenSSL](https://www.openssl.org/) command line tool like:

```
openssl s_client -connect jmeter-plugins.org:443
```

[image]

Pay attention to the certificate chain, mine looks as at the image above, in your case OpenSSL will print what's wrong. If there is an extra certificate you will need to import it into your [Truststore](https://www.baeldung.com/java-keystore-truststore-difference) and point JMeter to use this truststore by using the following JMeter System Properties:

```
# Truststore properties (trusted certificates)
javax.net.ssl.trustStore=/path/to/[jsse]cacerts
javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword
javax.net.ssl.trustStoreProvider
javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType [default = KeyStore.getDefaultType()]
```

More information:

- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)
- [Working with Certificates and SSL](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19830-01/819-4712/ablqw/index.html)

Comment: Hi Dmitri, thanks so much for such abundant information. I issue the command "openssl s_client -connect jmeter-plugin.org:443" and get the following reply "getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provide, or not know. connect: errno=0"

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can navigate to user.properties file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation) and paste the below line in user.properties file.

jpgc.repo.address=http://jmeter-plugins.org/repo/

JMeter restart will be required to pick the property up.